# Watchkit radio streaming

Tags: watchkit

I am trying to playback a streamed media (radio).

I have failed in the attempt and also I have received the error message: App Transport Security (ATS).

How I can play a streaming radio?

My first try:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ccma-radioa-int-abertis-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/int/mp4:catradio/chunklist.m3u8"];

WKAudioFileAsset *fileAsset = [WKAudioFileAsset assetWithURL:url];

WKAudioFilePlayerItem *playerItem = [WKAudioFilePlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:fileAsset];

self.audioPlayer = [WKAudioFilePlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];


if (self.audioPlayer.status == WKAudioFilePlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}
```

My second try:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ccma-radioa-int-abertis-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/int/mp4:catradio/chunklist.m3u8"];

NSDictionary *options = @{WKMediaPlayerControllerOptionsAutoplayKey:@YES};

[self presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL:url
                                  options:options
                               completion:^(BOOL didPlayToEnd, NSTimeInterval endTime, NSError * __nullable error) {
                                   if (!didPlayToEnd) {
                                       NSLog(@"The player did not play all the way to the end. The player only played until time - %.2f.", endTime);
                                   }

                                   if (error) {NSLog(@"There was an error with playback: %@.", error);}
                               }];
```

Does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: Have you tried to fix the ATS error? Any other effort will be pointless *until* your app is able to connect to the server.

Comment: You can not specify: App Transport Security -> Arbitrary loads on Watch App info.plist. In fact, the question is: how to play streaming radio? (on the Watch, of course)

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I'm seeing lots of live stream radio apps in the App Store but idk how they did it.

Comment: I do not remember. Sorry. This App was created long time ago. I would have to re-read the code.